# How to parse xml based on date value using xmlpullparser in android?

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

This is my xml.

```
 <alert>
    <code>DJNZLWYXEOLP</code>
    <datetime>18-07-2012 11:03</datetime>
    <alertcode>REPTAOBXCOKN</alertcode>
    <alert>DA Insurer Quote</alert>
    <description>New DA Insurer Quote Received</description>
    <reference>CN/FA/FCD/KCJ/11539</reference>
</alert>
<alert>
    <code>SLZCLWEEYBMX</code>
    <datetime>19-07-2012 11:30</datetime>
    <alertcode>PWQHXUNWSMVG</alertcode>
    <alert>AQE Insurer Quote</alert>
    <description>New AQE Insurer Quote Received</description>
    <reference>MXH/11431</reference>
</alert>
<alert>
    <code>AXHRLWEVCROG</code>
    <datetime>20-07-2012 11:35</datetime>
    <alertcode>LAEPLNGJSOXP</alertcode>
    <alert>New DA Automatically Approved</alert>
    <description>New DA Automatically Approved Case Received</description>
    <reference>PI/EIC/HFFT/HAR/11673</reference>
</alert>
<alert>
    <code>OSYVLWELBADI</code>
    <datetime>21-07-2012 11:44</datetime>
    <alertcode>LAEPLNGJSOXP</alertcode>
    <alert>New DA Automatically Approved</alert>
    <description>New DA Automatically Approved Case Received</description>
    <reference>CN/EIC/CLHF/HAR/11674</reference>
</alert>
<alert>
    <code>YUFOLWEMDXEU</code>
    <datetime>22-07-2012 11:50</datetime>
    <alertcode>LAEPLNGJSOXP</alertcode>
    <alert>New DA Automatically Approved</alert>
    <description>New DA Automatically Approved Case Received</description>
    <reference>PI/EIC/HFFT/HAR/11675</reference>
</alert>
<alert>
    <code>OGGWLWEXLGKB</code>
    <datetime>23-07-2012 13:18</datetime>
    <alertcode>REPTAOBXCOKN</alertcode>
    <alert>DA Insurer Quote</alert>
    <description>New DA Insurer Quote Received</description>
    <reference>PI/FA/FIB/LAN/11590</reference>
    </alert>
</alerts>
```

Here i want to parse xml based on datetime value. That is parsing have to begin after        20-07-2012 11:35. I tried this in xmlpullparser, it parses complete xml. But i want to parse after the datetime which is i have enter above. I am asking this because my xml having 300 records, all are not need to show in list, so anyone tell me how to show portion of the xml records.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No using PullParser i dont see how that is possible,but using SAX Parser, you may be able to achieve it.You cant escape parsing but what you can do is parse each entry till the datetime field & compare the the value with the value you want(20-07-2012 11:35)  if it is greater or equal to that date then you parse that element completetly & add it to a Array list and display all elements in the Array List.

If you meant the above in sense to reduce the time take to parse then i guess nobody can help you.(But you never know, a lot of brilliant minds are out here on StackOverflow)